# Two-Point Correlators in Conformal Field Theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, normalization

In a CFT we normalize the two-point correlators for two fundamental scalars as
$\langle\phi(x)\phi'(y)\rangle = \frac{\alpha\delta_{\phi\phi'}}{\left|x - y\right|^{2\Delta}}$ , where $\alpha$ is a normalization constant (usually we set it to one). This correlator is only non-zero if $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are the same field.

Now what I'm wondering is whether it would be possible to normalize the two-point correlators such that it's non-zero for two different fundamental scalars, something along the lines $\langle\phi(x)\phi'(y)\rangle = \frac{a_{\phi\phi'}}{\left|x - y\right|^{2\Delta}}$ , where $a_{\phi\phi'}$ could be non-zero even if $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are two different fields. If not, why?

Comment: 1) Since CFTs are typically not weakly-coupled, one rarely talks about "fundamental" operators -- it is not quite clear how to define what that means. 2) We do not normalize correlators, we choose bases of operators. Usually we choose a basis of operators in which two-point functions are diagonal, and this is always possible to do in unitary theories. 3) You can choose a basis where two-point functions are non-diagonal, but I see no reason how that can be convenient. Its akin to working in a non-orthonormal basis of a vector space -- one doesn't usually do that without a good reason.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk  could you make this into a real answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: there are often good reasons to consider non-diagonal bases, coherent states being a standard example which allow one to study emergence of semi classical physics out of quantum theory